# Using signalR in Ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, signalr

In angular I can use signalR, one of the requirements is to include the following script in index.html

```
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

In ionic 2, I get the following error:
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

How do I use this with ionic 2?

Answer (score 1):

Using full url seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use script tags in webpack builds. The location changes and the files is not found.

For signalR in ionic I suggest you use this module

https://www.npmjs.com/package/signalr-no-jquery

Comment: Thanks for response, the module specifies that it cannot be used with webapi core. I got it working with full url.